# Bootstrap Carousel/html5shiv installation

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using Bootstrap to create carousel. My pictures are not appearing but the glyphicons am using in the carousel are appearing.Can some one help me out please.
Below is my code with the bootstrap installation.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="yas.css">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Change100 community</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="js/html5shiv.min"></script>
      <script src="js/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#my-navbar">
<div class="container">
      <section>
        <div class="page-header" id="gallery">
          <h2>Gallery <small></small></h2>
        </div>
<div class="carousel slide" id="screenshot-carousel" data-ride="carousel">
          <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#screenshot-carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#screenshot-carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#screenshot-carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            <li data-target="#screenshot-carousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
          </ol>
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item">
              <img src="images/B.jpg" alt="this is the text for the image" class="active">
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <img src="images/2.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <img src="images/d1.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <img src="images/d.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
          </div><!--End carousel-inner-->
          <a href="#screenshot-carousel" class="left carousel-control" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
          </a>
          <a href="#screenshot-carousel" class="right carousel-control" data-slide="next">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
          </a>
        </div><!--End of carousel-->
      </section>
    </div>

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Any errors in browser console? Open it with F12 in your browser

Answer (score 0):

You should change the active class from this line :

```
<img src="images/B.jpg" alt="this is the text for the image" class="active">
```

To be in the div , like this :

```
<div class="item active">
   <img src="images/B.jpg" alt="this is the text for the image">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Ayadi baha. I did what you said and it works